# To check row number in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Here is my code:

```
foreach($jobs->result() as $job)
{  
    $table_data_rows.=get_jobs_data_row($job, $controller);
}

function get_jobs_data_row($job, $controller)
{
    if($job[0]) { }
}
```

how to check particular row number when we pass individual row as parameter in function as shown above in codeigniter

Comment: what do you mean by row number? is it element number in that row? because you are already passing a single row using get_jobs_data_row($job, $controller);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I can't pass additional parameters, since this function is reused in several parts and sometimes it will throw error, when we called directly get_jobs_data_row.

Hence I found myself, to check using the primary key.

For example:

```
function get_jobs_data_row($job, $controller)
{
    $key = $job->jobs_id;
    $controller->db->select_sum('pure');

    $sum_qry = $controller->db->get_where('jobs', array('jobs_id <= ' => $key));
    //code to retrieve


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to get a row from returned database data in codeigniter is `$result->row(rowNumber); considering $result contains result of query` (check the row() section on the following page http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

In your case you can pass each row with the reference of its row number like this:

```
$jobs = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
for($i=0; $i<$jobs->num_rows(); $i++)
{  
    $table_data_rows.=get_jobs_data_row($jobs->row($i), $controller, $i);
}

function get_jobs_data_row($job, $controller, $rowNum)
{
    if($rowNum == 0) { return $job; }
}
```

Comment: Actually I need whether it is first or second row from the result set, but I need in called function (here it is 2nd function).

Comment: answer updated according to your comment, hope that works for you!